# Rails3: warning: toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-3

Everytime i get a warning:

```
app/controllers/agency/agencies_controller.rb:1: warning: toplevel constant ApplicationController referenced by Agency::ApplicationController
```

My agencies_controller.rb:

```
class Agency::AgenciesController < Agency::ApplicationController

  def index
    ...
  end 

  ...
end
```

And Agency::ApplicationController:

```
class Agency::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  layout 'agency'

  helper_method :current_agency
  private

  def current_agency
    @current_agency ||= current_user.agency 
  end

end
```

What the rails wants from me? What is the trouble?

Same situation with another controller

```
class Agency::ClientsController < Agency::ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

And no warnings, no errors...

Answer (score 12):

I realize this question is almost two years old but I recently stumbled upon this through [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902023/rails-3-2-3-namespaced-controllers-being-overridden-by-global-controllers-with-s/10902980#10902980) stackoverflow post and wanted to share some insight.

Basically, if your namespace `Agency` happens to be a `class` instead of a `module`, you'll get that warning. In the stackoverflow post I pasted above, they had a model (`class`) of `Admin` and their namespace was also `Admin`.

[This](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/bab5e87ee10d2ecb?pli=1) provides a better explanation of what is happening.

So check to see if your code isn't defining an `Agency` class somewhere. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issues running `Spork` and `Watchr` in my `Admin` namespaced controllers. So i've fixed this by adding following code into `each_run` block in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
Dir[File.expand_path("app/controllers/admin/*.rb")].each do |file|
    require file
end
```

All credits goes to [guy from this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sporkgem/VN_R6IWtU3M)

Comment: Thanks this worked great, I modified it a bit though for brevity: Dir[Rails.root.join("app/controllers/admin/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

Comment: after hours of banging my head.. this resolved my issue.. good that i noticed that warning and good that i found this answer.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`ApplicationController` is the name of the superclass controller that Rails generates for you when you create a new project that all your other controller classes inherit from. There's probably a conflict somewhere because you've used the same name, even though you put it within a namespace.

Try giving your `Agency::ApplicationController` a different name.

Comment: But why there are no troubles with Agency::ClientsController??

Comment: Because `ClientsController` doesn't have a special meaning to Rails.

Comment: I have a functioning Admin::ApplicationController which doesn't give problems. So renaming should not be required. There is probably ambiguity elsewhere in the call stack, which Ruby is complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, after setting up `Spork` and `Watchr`. In the process, I turned off class cacheing (`config_cache_classes => false` in `config/environments/test.rb`) so that changes would be reloaded as necessary in the spork environment. Turning class cacheing `back on` made the warnings go away.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the problem with Devise. I had a devise model Admin and a namespaced routes  Admin. Changing the namespaced route to Admins solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was add this line:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
Dir[File.expand_path("app/controllers/admin/*.rb")].each { |file| require file }
```